# Analyzing a small-signal MOSFET circuit

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

This is the problem:
[image]

And this my solution:
[image]

Is it correct ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Good job. (I wish all my students wrote this well.)

Comment: Thank you :). Can you check this solution too please : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/141237/analyzing-a-mosfet-amplifier-circuit

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with that one.